# Redux-form - Is there a way to know what fields have been changed? (update & PATCH)

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form

When updating an entity using `redux-form`, I'd like to know what fields have been changed, in order to use a PATCH HTTP request on those fields only. (and not sent the whole form)

Is there a built-in way to do that? I'm looking at the doc and it doesn't seem to be any option for that, yet.

http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Props.md/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing it on submit? You could manually diff `values` with `this.props.initialValues` to determine the changed values.

Comment: That's finally how I did it. I used https://github.com/srcagency/object-diff for the `diff` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Each field has a "dirty" property. Seems to be what you're looking for:

> true if the current value is different from the initialized value, false otherwise.

http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md/#-dirty-boolean-

You'd need to keep a list of all "dirty" fields but that should be doable with a `.filter()`

Comment: I thought the `dirty` only applied to the whole form, could be the right way to go indeed. :)